# No automatic handling for Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, python-3.4

I am using `urllib.request`.  If I set Accept-Encoding to `gizp, deflate` the data returned is a compressed stream, and a traffic savings of 60% to 80%. Is there an option to automatically decompress the data or must I handle it myself?  If the latter, what are the appropriate tools to use?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend switching from `urllib` to [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It automatically [handles gziped data](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/community/faq/#encoded-data).

An example:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
>>> r.text
u'[{"id":"2978193412","type":"PushEvent","actor":{"id":13182197,"login":"ClothoWong","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/...
```

(Clipped for brevity)

Above, you see some nice, pretty JSON, but it actually downloaded using the GZIP encoding:

```
>>> r.raw.getheaders()['Content-Encoding']
'gzip'
```

(You can also confirm that the endpoint responds with gzip encoding via your favorite browser developer tool.)

`requests` is, in my opinion, a superior option to `urllib`, anyway. You'll end up with far less, simpler code to do the same things.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I am too invested in `urllib` in the current project.  Will consider `requests` for new work.  The answer to my question is: `zlib.decompress(gizppedContent, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)`.

Comment: @OldGeezer You can switch now. `requests` can be used for any new work sending requests (including the currently incomplete task) and old work can be left alone until it needs to be changed. That said, `requests` is so much more intuitive and simple to use, you *really* should weigh the cost of continuing to use `urllib` vs. the ramp up cost of `requests`. I think you'll find that you'll very quickly be spending more time trying to figure out `urllib` than you would have learning `requests`. Being "too heavily invested" in an improper abstraction usually ends up costing more pretty quickly.